# ASP.NET and Google Drive DLL

Tags: google-drive-api

I plan to create a package which contains a Google Drive integration. Our customers can install this package on whose IIS (asp.net) to use it in the web-application. Client-ID und secret should be allways the same(our data). We have also running multiple web sites with this packes. The redirect-url is allways differen(subdomain/domain/directory of customers/our sites.

Which API-Type do I need?
With Client ID for web applications, I have to note every URL of customers and our sites.

Is there an example with asp.net (without VMC but propably vb.net) and the Google Drive API (DLL)?
I've seen a lot of notes but in the most cases, the URL etc. are created manualy.

Best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that client ID, client secret secret and redirect URI are configurable with a config file and for each deployment provide a different file.

Comment: And then, every customer has to go to API Console and create a new ID?
Is it not possible that we create on ID and all uses this on(with out title,Logo,...)?

Comment: The appropriate usage is to create a client ID for each customer/application.